# How do I connect to mysql DB when github CI stage?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, continuous-integration, supertest

I am not knowledgeable about devops. I need your help.

I created an API test code using jest and supertest, and I want to connect to a db to test it on Github ci.

First, let me tell you about the current status of this project.
This is not immediately resolved by simply doing `npm run test.`
Since it is difficult to separate the server and app objects, the test code was executed using `npm run test` while the server was running locally through `npm run start:dev`.

Also, I would like to conduct this test at the CI stage. This means that you want to run tests at a stage that automatically runs when you push your source code to GitHub.

Since the server must be started, it was successful that the server was started by running the `npm run start:dev &` command in the background.

After that, I entered `npm run test`, but an error occurred because I could not connect to the DB, and the test could not proceed.

Keys related to database are managed by AWS kms, that is, it is difficult to take them out and use them.

In this embarrassing situation, is there a way to run test code at the CI level? When I run `npm run test`, I want to see the same test results as in the local environment.